# Difference between ':button' and 'button' as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button value="">Button 1</button>
        <button value="">Button 2</button>
        <button value="">Button 3</button>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is code in custom.js

```
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

and when I changed the code in custom.js to

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

They do the same work that is display alert on click,But I want to know the difference between `'button'` and `':button'`

Comment: Did you even read the jQuery documentation? It's extremely clear on this.

Comment: Thanks for that documentation reference , didn't knew earlier about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using only `button` will select only `<button></button>` elements, while `:button` will select `<button></button>` and `<input type="button" />`

See https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/ for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`button` only selects the `button` elements, whereas `:button` also selects the `input type="button"`

Answer (score 3):

`$(':button')` selects `<button>` tags or `<input />` tags with `type="button"`

`$('button')` selects only `<button>` tags

```js
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    alert('You clicked a tag of type: ' + $(this).prop('tagName'));
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert('Hello from ' + ($(this).html() || $(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button value="">Button 1</button>
<button value="">Button 2</button>
<button value="">Button 3</button>      

<input type="button" value="Input Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

$(":button") : selects both "button" tag and "input type=button" as well

while $("button") : only selects

Comment: i didnt miss the tags! apparently when i typed it as < b u t t o n > it disappeared from the sentence.